# How to restore unsaved ADF pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to restore unsaved work in ADF? I had several pipelines that weren't committed or pushed to GIT repository when suddenly my PC was crushed so I lost my work.
Any idea how can I restore it?

I can see the history of its debug runs and have pipeline run ids. Maybe, there is a way to get a JSON code of the particular RunID or at least inner activities?

Comment: If  my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to restore unsaved ADF pipeline.

To avoid this situation in future, you can take backup and restore pipeline. Please refer this [article](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2021/10/copy-or-clone-data-factory-in-azure.html).

If you have ARM template, then you can restore ADF pipeline.

Refer - [How to Restore Azure Data Factory from ARM Template](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFhFlMlOa58&t=59s)